# Ruby/Watir: Clicking elements with role="button"

Tags: ruby, button, watir, role

I'm trying to write a script that will automatically click a button when entering a site.

The HTML of the site is as follows:

```
<span id="zolaDisclaimerButton" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" waistate="labelledby-zolaDisclaimerButton_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="zolaDisclaimerButton_label" tabindex="0" title="I acknowledge this disclaimer... Let ZoLa begin!" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
```

I have tried the following and they don't work:

```
browser.span(:id, "zolaDisclaimerButton").click
browser.button(:id, "zolaDisclaimerButton").click
```

How do I go about clicking those types of button?  The URL in question is:
http://gis.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/template?applicationName=ZOLA

EDIT: this is the code I use:

```
require "watir"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://gis.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/template?applicationName=ZOLA"
browser.span(:id, "zolaDisclaimerButton").click
puts "fin"
```

It navigates to the page, doesn't click anything, then prints 'fin' (to let me know it's done).  No exception is thrown.

Comment: Please expand on "they don't work". Is there an exception?

Comment: updated original post

Comment: I was able to run your script successfully using IE9, Firefox and Chrome. Which browser are you using and are all your gems up-to-date?

Comment: So it was working on and off for me.  I figured it out; the internet speed here is abysmal and I guess the disclaimer loads a little after the page itself does... after adding a `sleep 2` before the click, it works consistently.  Is there a more elegant way to wait until everything on a page is loaded before continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is not loading in time, you can add waits - see http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/. These wait methods will wait until either the condition is met or a time limit is exceeded. It is better than using `sleep` since it only waits as long as needed (rather than waiting 2 seconds for something that loads in 1 second).

In this case, use the `when_present` method on the span before clicking it:

```
require "watir"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://gis.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/template?applicationName=ZOLA"
browser.span(:id, "zolaDisclaimerButton").when_present.click
puts "fin"
```